# how to Configuration both Appender class in config file using log4j

Tags: java, struct, log4j

DailyRollingFileAppender -- day wise rolling,
RollingFileAppender -- size wise rolling --
But i want both condition in single Appender

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Log4j Extras Companion](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/index.html). You need to use a [SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html) along with a [TimeBasedRollingPolicy](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html) in your appender.

More info on this [log4j-user thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/log4j-user@logging.apache.org/msg09823.html).